# Java: What's the faster way to sort subsets of non-consecutive string characters using Java 8 API

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting

I have this Java code snippet

```
String str = "acxrabdz"; 
int[] pos = {1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1};
```

Where equal values in `pos` means that the corresponding characters in `str` belong to the same subset. I want to sort in lexicographically descending order the characters in each subset. In the example the subsets are
`1: {{a, pos: 0}, {x, pos: 2}, {b, pos: 5}, {z, pos: 7}}`
`2: {{c, pos: 1}, {d, pos: 6}}`
`3: {{r, pos: 3}}`
`4: {{a, pos: 4}}`
and the ordered subsets
`1: {{z, pos: 0}, {x, pos: 2}, {b, pos: 5}, {a, pos: 7}}`
`2: {{d, pos: 1}, {c, pos: 6}}`
`3: {{r, pos: 3}}`
`4: {{a, pos: 4}}`
The answer will be `String ans = "zdxrabca";`
I just want to obtain the final string not the intermediate subsets.
How can I solve that using the fastest Java 8 approach and if possible in place?

Comment: According to your explanation, the correct answer would be `adcrzxba`. Please update the explanation or show your current algorithm. Also, non-ascending = descending :)

Comment: Based on dasblinkenlight's comment, @Titan can you explain why "zdxrabca" is the only acceptable answer and "zxbadcra" is wrong?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight wrt "non-ascending" vs "descending" - there's no need for uniqueness. "non-ascending" is any ordering that is not ascending. The characters "acb" are presented in a non-ascending order, although they are definitely not in a descending order.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have changed the sort type to descending and explained the example.

Comment: What do you mean by "...and if possible in place"?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm

Comment: @FabianBarney it's impossible to work in-place with Java strings as they're immutable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It seems that joining the sorted characters should be based on original position asc. So only characters of the same subset may switching positions.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I know, but you asked what he meant with "... and if possible in place".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that lets you do it in a straightforward way with additional storage of pre-allocated size. It assumes that all values in the `pos[]` array are in the range from 1 to N, inclusive, where N is the number of characters in `str`.

The algorithm is very straightforward. See comments for an explanation of what is happening.

```
char[] str = "acxrabdz".toCharArray();
int[] pos = {1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1};
int[] len = new int[pos.length];
// Count how many characters are in each group
for (int n : pos) {
    len[n-1]++;
}
// Pre-allocate space for each group of characters
char[][] tmp = new char[pos.length][];
for (int i = 0 ; i != pos.length ; i++) {
    if (len[i] != 0) {
        tmp[i] = new char[len[i]];
    }
}
// Scatter characters from the string into their group arrays
int[] tpos = new int[pos.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i != pos.length ; i++) {
    int p = pos[i]-1;
    tmp[p][tpos[p]++] = str[i];
}
// Sort each individual group in ascending order
for (int i = 0 ; i != pos.length ; i++) {
    if (tmp[i] != null) {
        Arrays.sort(tmp[i]);
    }
}
// Put characters back into the string starting at the back
for (int i = 0 ; i != pos.length ; i++) {
    int p = pos[i]-1;
    str[i] = tmp[p][--tpos[p]];
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/yUfZVy)